# Reading sql file using getResources in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read and execute a sql in SPARK SQL.

`sqlContext.sql(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/" + "dq.sql")).getLines.mkString(" ").stripMargin).take(1)`

My sql is very long. When I run it straight way in spark shell , it runs fine. When I try to read this using getResourcesAsStream - I'm hitting

`java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.10930] failure: end of input`

Comment: How are you including db.sql in your resources? It seems like it might not be getting included.

Comment: I have resources folder with following structure ETL/src/main/Resources/dq.sql

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be reading the sql at driver (using any file utility) and pass the variable like ssc.sql(sqlvar)

Answer (score 0):

```
  val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/filename.txt")
  val readFile = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines

  val spa = readFile.map(line => " " + line)
  val spl = spa.mkString.split(";")

  for (m1 <- spl) {
    sqlContext.sql(m1)
  }
```